# std::getline and posix signals

Tags: c++, timer, posix, getline

I have a simple program that starts a recurring timer and then settles into a getline loop parsing any input data. However, whenever the timer signal occurs it is ending the getline function, which looks as if the user has pressed enter. How can I stop the signal doing this? Or failing that, how can I differentiate between a genuine return press and the signal? The latter is less desirable, as I will then have to run this differentiation code at 400Hz.

Below is the code I am currently using to get a line. A blank input will reprint the APP > line, while any other input passes through.

```
do
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        line.clear();
        std::cout << "APP > ";
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
    }
    while (line.length() == 0);
```

Thanks all

Matt

Comment: You don't check the state of `std::cin`. I wonder if the failbit is set after an alarm goes off.

Comment: Aha, that appears to be along the right lines. I had previously tried comparing the direct state of failbit and badbit with no luck, but it seems using the fail() function does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I made the comment an answer so you can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the state of `std::cin`. I wonder if the failbit is set after an alarm goes off.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your problem, nor can I reproduce it. The following program reads from stdin correctly *and* handles signals; neither gets in the way of the other:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void handle(int n)
{
    static unsigned int count = 0;

    std::cout << "Signal: " << n << std::endl;  // not safe, I know...

    if (++count == 5)
    {
        std::cout << "Too many signals, goodbye!\n";
        std::exit(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, handle);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
    {
        std::cout << "You said: " << line << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "End of input, goodbye!\n";
}
```